# Easy way to pull fully qualified field names from a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, is there an easy way to output a list of fully qualified field names from a SELECT statement, even with aliases?

For example:

```
SELECT
      a.FieldName1
    , a.FieldName2
    , CASE WHEN a.FieldName9 = 'A' and b.FieldName10 = 'C' Then 'Yes' Else 'No' END as AliasedCase
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Table1 a
JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.Table2 b on a.FieldName4 = b.FieldName4
WHERE b.FieldName8 Between 1 and 4
```

Output list would look like:

1. DatabaseA.dbo.Table1.FieldName1
2. DatabaseA.dbo.Table1.FieldName2
3. DatabaseA.dbo.Table1.FieldName4
4. DatabaseA.dbo.Table1.FieldName9
5. DatabaseB.dbo.Table2.FieldName4
6. DatabaseB.dbo.Table2.FieldName8
7. DatabaseB.dbo.Table2.FieldName10

Comment: No easy way, just the manual way.

Comment: Create a view out of your query, then take your information from [`sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view or procedure with that `SELECT`, use the `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` function to get the information, then drop it afterwards.

```
create view dbo.MyTempView
as

SELECT
      a.FieldName1
    , a.FieldName2
    , CASE WHEN a.FieldName9 = 'A' and b.FieldName10 = 'C' Then 'Yes' Else 'No' END as AliasedCase
FROM DatabaseA.dbo.Table1 a
JOIN DatabaseB.dbo.Table2 b on a.FieldName4 = b.FieldName4
WHERE b.FieldName8 Between 1 and 4
```

```sql
select CONCAT(
  dep.referenced_server_name + '.',
  dep.referenced_database_name + '.',
  dep.referenced_schema_name + '.',
  dep.referenced_entity_name + '.',
  dep.referenced_minor_name)
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.MyTempView', 'OBJECT') dep
where dep.referenced_minor_name is not null;
```

```sql
drop view dbo.MyTempView;
```

The use of `CONCAT` along with `+ '.'` means that nulls will be ignored along with their associated `.`, so it will only tell you the actual reference you used, it will not work out which database or schema is used if you did not specify it (due to scoping issues, as it depends what your default database and schema is when executed).